# Duplicate output destination - OleDB

Tags: c#

I have an insert query that I am trying to execute under a foreach loop to insert multiple values. However, when I add more than one textbox row, I get an error saying `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Duplicate output destination at 'childName'`

Here is my code:

```
 // use LINQ to fetch all the children textboxes
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = tabCtrl1.TabPages["tabPage1"].Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
     .Where(t => t.TabIndex >= startTabIndex && t.TabIndex <= endTabIndex && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text))
     .OrderBy(f => f.TabIndex)
     .Select(x => new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Name, x.Text))
     .ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.Value);

     // loop through all the children textboxes
     // and assign them to the list members.childTextBoxes
     foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary)
     {
         members.childTextBoxes.Add(new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>($"{kvp.Key}", $"{kvp.Value}"));
     }

 var mapToDatabase = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();

 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild1), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild1Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild1Email), "childEmail");

 // child 2
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild2), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild2Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild2Email), "childEmail");

 // child 3
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild3), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild3Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild3Email), "childEmail");

 // child 4
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild4), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild4Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild4Email), "childEmail");

 // child 5
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild5), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild5Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild5Email), "childEmail");

 // child 6
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild6), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild6Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild6Email), "childEmail");

 // child 7
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild7), "childName");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild7Birthday), "birthday");
 mapToDatabase.Add(nameof(textBoxChild7Email), "childEmail");


 string fieldList = $"{string.Join(",", members.childTextBoxes.Select(tb => mapToDatabase[tb.Key]))}";
 string valueList = $"{string.Join(",", members.childTextBoxes.Select(tb => "?"))}";

 string insertQuery = $"INSERT INTO children (pid, {fieldList}) VALUES (?,{valueList})";



   using (members.DBCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, members.DBConnection))
   { 
        foreach (var field in members.childTextBoxes)
        {                       
           members.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", lastInsertId);
           members.DBCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + field.Key, OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = field.Value;

            if (members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) // error line
            {                       
               members.DBCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }


        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted", "QBC", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        // clear the fields
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
               ((TextBox)c).Clear();
            }
        }
   }
```

I think it has to do with the `map.ToDatabase.Add()` part. Is there a way to avoid this and still execute the insert query for each textbox field that is filled out? Everything else is working fine, I just can't add more than one textbox row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't give enough information to provide a clear answer. But what you need is a method after each child to insert the record into the database. If you give more details on the kind of object mapToDatabase is, I can help further.

Comment: it maps all the children textboxes to a dictionary object with the textboxes names to the keys and sets the database table column names as the values and then builds the field list and value list from a keyvaluepair where they all are stored (members.childTextBoxes)

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: 291 ( if (members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) )

Comment: but i know the problem is with the mapToDatabase

Comment: I just can't figure out how to build the insert query to insert all non empty values in the foreach without running into the error I am getting

Comment: It doesn't look like you're executing the command in the foreach, but you are adding the parameters for EVERY addition you made when using mapToDatabase. Do each of the textboxes have the same name? (i.e. nameof(textBoxChild1) and nameof(textBoxChild2)) If those are the same, you're trying to add the exact parameter names over and over again.

Comment: no, each textbox has a different name

Comment: trying to add all textboxes or the ones just filled out to insert (might be more than one filled out)

Comment: What does the insert query turn out to be? Are fieldList and valueList what you're expecting them to be?

If you're wanting an end data structure with only 3 fields, you only want to create 3 parameters before an insert. You'll need a way to differentiate the separate childs (try creating a Child class maybe), each with 3 properties (name, birthday, and email). Then your command will need to be inside the looping of each child to insert each record.

Comment: The error is plainly stating that you're duplicating field names in your insert.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209781(v=office.12).aspx

INSERT queries should be something like...
INSERT INTO tableName ('pID', 'childName', 'birthday', 'childEmail') VALUES (valueforpID, valueforchildName, valueforbirthday, valueforchildEmail) 

Then this would need to be performed for each child record. I hope that make sense! You need to inspect your query and determine if it is a valid query; it seems like you're trying to bulk insert with 21 parameters + IDs  (a VERY wide table).

Comment: no, there are only 4 columns in the table but i want to insert one after the one

Comment: Yes, so you need an INSERT statement with 4 column names that are not duplicated. And you will need to do this for every row you want inserted.

You current code adds a bunch of parameters in a loop that includes every textbox then tries to execute the command once. The error is indicating that the childName parameter is duplicated, which it doesn't like.

Comment: the column names are pid, childName, childBirthday and childEmail. I would want to use those over again to insert a new record(s)

Comment: I get that. But that isn't what your code is doing. It is telling you that you're duplicating a field/column name. And because your insert is not in the loop, it is only being executed once...for a single insert.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're using the key value pair? If there are always only up to 7 children, you could make this much simpler by concatenating strings for your query.

Comment: I was just trying to be organized.

Comment: Okay. If it doesn't make a difference to you, look up string builders. Focus on creating your insert query properly for each child. Put a breakpoint in your code before trying to execute the command and see what the value of insertQuery is.

Comment: if the map thing is the issue (which I think it is) would it be better off to insert after each textbox row?

Comment: The issue is that the query is not correct because of how you have the logic laid out. You could perform an insert after each textbox just to get it working.

Comment: this is the value of the insert query (screenshot) - https://imgur.com/Ort4eYV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155363/discussion-between-h-and-user2101411).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **members.DBCommand.Parameters.Clear()** someplace after you run **members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()**. You also should have the **members.DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()** function call inside the for loop that processes **members.childTextBoxes** dictionary items.

By clearing the parameters collection, you are prepping for the next query.

Does that help?

**EDIT:**
Your approach is a bit unorthodox, to say the least. But it can work. Here are some pointers for you:

1. Construct by hand the DBCommand CommandText and Parameters you require in order to insert data from textBoxChild1, textBox1Birthday, textBoxChild1EMail, and any other fields you need. Once you get that working, do it again with textBoxChild2 and see what changes. Construct your loop so that each iteration adjusts the insert query and parameters as needed.
2. Consider getting away from the use of textBoxChild1 and childName dictionary mappings. Instead, create a Child object and then create a generic list of Child objects (i.e., List< Child >). In that generic list, each list element will be a child object. You can then construct your database operations by iterating through the list. There are plenty of examples that illustrate how to iterate across generic list objects in C#.
3. If you have textboxes on your front-end UI that have rows of information, use a grid instead. You shouldn't have a textBoxChild1 UI element and a textBoxChild2 element--that is a nightmare to manage especially if you need to add a new Child7 or Child8 or if you have more fields to add for each child. You need to find a design that lends itself to collections and objects and the construct your insert queries accordingly.

Don't be too hard on yourself. Your initial design is very flawed and I do not recommend keeping it just because you invested time in it. Its design should be changed for readability and maintainability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155395/discussion-on-answer-by-jazimov-duplicate-output-destination-oledb). Please remember to incorporate all relevant information back into the answer by [edit]ing.